Change time format in GCP Logs Explorer
I'm currently using GCP's Logs Explorer and I'm wondering if it's possible to see 12-hr time format in the log timestamps? I just find it more readable.

I found the options to hide the time zone and date, but I couldn't find any setting to change the time format.

There is no option to change to 12h format in gcp logs explorer.
Gcp will be using this format [START\_TIME\_ISO] and [END\_TIME\_ISO]: the start and end times in ISO 8601 format (example: 2023-02-21T07:00:00.000Z).
We can request GCP to include this feature, I have raised this feature request on behalf of you. Moreover, I suggest you to track this feature request to get notified on the updates of roll out (please CC yourself). As per my understanding feature requests have no ETA and no guarantee of implementation but you can always add comments for the feature request in the issue tracker requesting updates. I also recommend you to add a star(+1) to this Feature Request as when it has more stars it will receive more priority than other feature requests with less stars.

Thanks for clarifying and the feature request (+1 on GCP)
